# Comparação de elementos iguais e exclusão C++

Tags: c#, c, c++, dev-c++

Estou quebrando a cabeça para resolver um exercício, preciso criar um programa que insira elementos em uma lista encadeada e depois criar uma função para verificar se dentre os elementos exista elementos iguais, e se assim for, excluir todas as repetições.

Não sei se devo utilizar uma função recursiva para isso, tentei fazer uma verificação com um ponteiro auxiliar, comparando cada elemento com os restantes, mas não consegui.

```cpp
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct no{
    int n;
    no *prox;
};

struct lista{
    no *inicio;
};

int menu(){
    int op;
    cout << "\nl. Inserir na lista\n";
    cout << "2. Remover da lista\n";
    cout << "3. Imprimir lista\n";
    cout << "4. Sair\n";
    cout << "Opcao: ";
    cin >> op;
    return op;  
}
no* criarNo(){
    int num;
    cout << "Qual numero quer inserir: ";
    cin >> num;
    no *novo = new no;
    novo->n = num;
    novo->prox = NULL;
    return novo;
}

void inserirLista(lista *l){
    no *insere = criarNo();
    if(l->inicio == NULL){
        l->inicio = insere;
    }
    else{
        no *aux = l->inicio;
        if(aux->n > insere->n){
            insere->prox = l->inicio;
            l->inicio = insere;
        }else {
            while(aux->prox != NULL && aux->prox->n < insere->n){
                aux = aux->prox;
            }
            insere->prox = aux->prox;
            aux->prox = insere;
        }
    }   
}

void imprimirLista(lista *inicio){
    if(inicio->inicio == NULL)
        cout << "Lista vazia\n";
    else{
        no *aux = inicio->inicio;
        while(aux->prox != NULL){
            cout << aux->n << " ";
            aux = aux->prox;
        }
        cout << aux->n << " ";      
    }
}

void removerRepetidos(lista *l){
/*  while(aux->prox != NULL){
        if(aux->n == aux->prox){
            aux->prox = aux->prox->prox;
        }
        else()
    }*/
}

int main(){
    int opcao;
    lista *l = new lista;
    l->inicio = NULL;
    while(true){
        opcao = menu();
        switch(opcao){
            case 1:
                inserirLista(l);
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Remover numeros repetidos: ";
                removerRepetidos(l);
                break;
            case 3:
                imprimirLista(l);
                break;
            case 4:
                return -1;
            default:
                cout << "Opcao invalida\n";
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar um `set` para ir armazendo os valores dos nós e caso voce encontre um valor que ja exista nesse set pode eliminar o nó. Lembre de adicionar a biblioteca `#include <set>`

```
void removerRepetidos(lista *l) {
    set<int> elementos_passados;
    no *atual = l->inicio;
    no *anterior;
    while(atual != NULL) {
        if(elementos_passados.find(atual->n) != elementos_passados.end()) {
            // esse elemento ja foi encontrado na lista

            // delete o elemento atual
            anterior->prox = atual->prox;
        } else {
            // adiciona o elemento no set
            elementos_passados.insert(atual->n);
            anterior = atual;
        }

        atual = atual->prox;
    }
}
```